# Facebook keyword search with 'OR' condition

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Can somebody please confirm that Facebook keyword search with 'OR' condition is working or not working via Graph API or FQL?

I tried my self and found its not working. i.e search for "Ann or Kevin" but the same works when you search for "Ann and Kevin"

Can somebody, please confirm it is working or not. please post simple example for Graph API or FQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/

**Quote:**

> Queries are of the form `SELECT [fields] FROM [table] WHERE
>   [conditions]`. Unlike SQL, the FQL `FROM` clause can contain only a
>   single table. You can use the `IN` keyword in `SELECT` or `WHERE`
>   clauses to do subqueries, but the subqueries cannot reference
>   variables in the outer query's scope. Your query must also be
>   indexable, meaning that it queries properties that are marked as
>   indexable in the documentation below.
>
> FQL can handle simple math, basic boolean operators, `AND` or `NOT`
>   logical operators, and `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses. `ORDER BY` can
>   contain only a single table.

So no, there is no `OR` operator in FQL. However you can write `field in ('Ann', 'Kevin')` and this will work like `OR` operator.